# Access Images from Phone Class Library

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, windows-phone-8

I have created a Phone Class Library(name is Base) with MainPage.xaml. I am linking this file in my Sub Project. As all the class files are linked from Base, I am able to run the Sub Project.

The problem Im facing is, I want to access the image files from my Sub Projects (which are present in my Sub Project). For example I have my Sub Project's image in Assets folder. My code is

```
Image image = new Image();
Uri imageUri = new Uri("Assets/Topic1.png", UriKind.Relative);
image.Source = new BitmapImage(imageUri);
image.Width = 48;
image.Height = 48;
ContentPanelChildren.Add(image);
```

This piece of code does not show my image which is in "Assets/Topic1.png" location.

How do I display the image?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the Uri line to this:

```
Uri imageUri = new Uri("/ASSEMBLY NAME;component/Assets/Topic1.png", UriKind.Relative);
```

Replace "ASSEMBLY NAME" with the name of your assembly.